# Cannot get data-tile-size to work in KendoUI Color Picker

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am trying to use a Kendo-UI Color Picker with a custom palette and tile size. I am using the MVVM pattern, so I am using declarative initialization. I cannot, however, get the tile size to be anything other than the default 14 x 14 square.

I initially thought it was something specific in my own project, but I then used an example from Kendo's docs in their dojo playground, and I can't make it work there either. Here is my modification of their code to try to incorporate the custom palette and tile size:

```
<input data-role="colorpicker"
       data-bind="visible: isVisible,
                  enabled: isEnabled,
                  value: selectedColor,
                  events: { change: onChange }"
       data-palette="['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f']" 
       data-tile-size="{ width: 30, height: 30 }">
```

Link to the dojo: http://dojo.telerik.com/uTUxU/3

Things I've thought of already:

(1) I wondered at first if only the colorpalette and not the colorpicker had a tile size property, but the documentation suggested otherwise. I then confirmed with a different dojo that a colorpicker can have a different tile size, though that was jQuery initialization instead of declarative style used for MVVM.

(2) I found an example from the company's blog confirming that data-tile-size is the correct form of the data attribute (at least for a colorpalette, which should be the same).

(3) I tried using other properties such as data-columns after data-palette instead there was a subtle formatting mistake preventing other attributes from being parsed. They worked as expected.

(4) I tried using just 30 instead of the object representation since I want it to be square anyway, and that didn't help.

(5) Even though I was pretty sure it wouldn't help, I tried formatting the object in JSON string format with quotes around the property names. I was right; it didn't help.

So now I'm stumped, and I'm not sure if there really is a very subtle problem, or if I'm making a silly Kendo newbie mistake. Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiles widht & height are set with .k-colorpalette .k-item css class

```
.k-colorpalette .k-item {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-high-contrast-adjust: none;
}
```

You can override it .

```
 .k-colorpalette .k-item {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        overflow: hidden;
        -ms-high-contrast-adjust: none;
    }
```

http://dojo.telerik.com/uTUxU/7

Comment: That does it. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

The tile size can only ever be used when one makes use of a the **kendo-color-palette**

There are 3 main attributes that determine the color picker that will be styled for Kendo UI. *kendo-color-palette* being one of them. If you use *kendo-colorpicker* or *kendo-flat-color-picker* the tile size will simply not work as they are not palatte styled.

In your posted snippet you have **data-role="colorpicker"** which i assume is the MVVM equivelant of the attribute kendo-color-picker, so simply change it to the palette one. ex: data-role="color-palette" and it should work.

Hope this helps